# Function mcrypt_get_iv_size(), mcrypt_create_iv(), mcrypt_encrypt() is deprecated on Codeigniter 5.6 to upgrade 7.1

Tags: php, codeigniter, web-development-server

[image]
How to Solve these error when upgrade codeigniter version 5.6 to 7.1 ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Fatal error: Call to undefined function mcrypt\_encrypt()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2604435/fatal-error-call-to-undefined-function-mcrypt-encrypt)

Comment: What are "these error"? Can you share them in text form?