# How to integrate the CCAvenue using Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, payment-gateway, ccavenue

In my application, I have integrated CCAvenue using Core PHP.

Now I need to do the same in laravel framework also, I am already have Merchant Id, Working Key and Access code information. I doesn't get proper documents to configure the credentials in Laravel package.

I referred the following link to laravel & CCAevenue configuration, but I didn't get the proper details.

https://github.com/softon/indipay

Can anyone help me to overcome from the issue.

Comment: Can we get more detail like what you get after all of your action ?

Comment: in src/config/config.php you can configure Merchant Id, Working Key

Answer (score 0):

The link you provided you can find page location src/config/config.php and update the key

```
'merchantId'  => env('INDIPAY_MERCHANT_ID', 'here_place_your_merchant_id'),
'accessCode'  => env('INDIPAY_ACCESS_CODE', 'here_place_your_access_code'),
'workingKey' => env('INDIPAY_WORKING_KEY', 'here_place_your_working_key'),
```

Comment: thanks for your response. I followed the same in the URL link (https://github.com/softon/indipay) and getting the following error in ubuntu.

"Call to undefined function Softon\Indipay\Gateways\mcrypt_module_open()"

Could you help me to fix that issue

Comment: can you please check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2604435/fatal-error-call-to-undefined-function-mcrypt-encrypt